# Crear un registro y obtener su ID inmediatamente Mysql

Tags: mysql

Básicamente estoy haciendo un sistema de reportes en Java escritorio y estoy usando MySQL como base de datos.

Resulta que quiero tengo un panel administrador con un botón de crear reporte. Y quisiera obtener en el siguiente JFRAME el numero de reporte con el que se va a guardar (la cual es la PK de la tabla de reportes y la tengo autoincrementable). Mi opinión sería:

1. Crear un reporte en blanco nada mas presionar
2. Consultar dicho reporte para ver que ID obtuvo y así colocarlo en el JFRAME
3. Rellenar los campos y luego actualizar el registro.

Este software va a estar instalado en muchos PC's y van a compartir una misma base de datos por lo que puede pasar que dos personas estén al mismo tiempo creando un reporte y no quiero que se generen conflictos.
Mi pregunta seria, ¿existe alguna forma de realizar la consulta y obtener el ID del registro automáticamente?

Otra solución sería:

1. Lanzar el jframe sin el numero de reporte
2. Rellenar los campos y presionar enviar reporte
3. El botón crea el reporte completo
4. Hacer una consulta del registro inmediatamente creado, tomar su ID y mandarlo por un JOPTIONPANE al usuario para que sepa cual fue el id con el que se guardo dicho reporte.

Pero volvemos a tener el mismo inconveniente. Como hago para que esa consulta sea casi instantánea?
Bien puedo filtrar la consulta por el nombre del técnico que la hace, pero que comando uso en SQL para obtener solo el ultimo registro, ejemplo:

```
select idreporte from tbreportes where idtecnico='usuarioejemplo' and (aqui vendria la condicion de que me muestre el ultimo registro hecho por el);
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: mepa que va por el lado de ejecutar la query con [Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que quieres que sea 'instantáneo' Podrías hacer un procedimiento almacenado que ejecute el insert y luego obtenga el id del último reporte como lo reportó el compañero Darwin.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo quiere que no se tenga conflicto con el los id del reporte.
Si estas usando el PK y lo tienes autoincremetal no debes preocuparte por eso, la base de datos gestiona automáticamente los id y no se va a generar conflicto.

Si quieres obtener el último registro puedes usar esta query SQL:

```
SELECT idreporte FROM tbreportes WHERE idtecnico='usuarioejemplo' ORDER BY id_table DESC LIMIT 1
```

Esta sentencia MySql te muestra el último registro de dicha tabla. Hace la consulta, ordena al descendente mente y limita a uno el resultado.

O puedes utilizar esta query más corta.

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM name_table
```

Answer (score 0):

select **last_insert_id()**
Con eso solucionas la vida hermano.
Es el mejor método, dado que el expuesto en la respuesta previa no garantiza que obtengas el id si estás en un ambiente multiusuario. Simplemente te da el mayor. Este método, te devuelve el último ID creado en una tabla donde has hecho un insert y tiene una columna auto numérica como indice, y en tu misma sesión.